# Looking for a good DDOS IPS system

Tags: security, ddos, ips

Could I get some recommendations on an IPS solutions that incorporates some form of DDOS protection / what do you currently implement on your network?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move this question across to [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/) - as it is an ideal question for that forum. A couple of us have tested/used DDoS solutions at an enterprise level. The one I am aware of required the ISP and DDoS protection provider to work together so a solution for you may be local specific.